# Max function behavior

Tags: python

I'm reading the Python tutorial. Does anyone know how this code works if `max()` expects a list?

```
>>> class student:
...     def __init__(self, gpa, name):
...         self.gpa = gpa
...         self.name = name
... 
>>> graduates = [student(1.0, "nick"), student(2.0, "geoff")]
>>> m = max((s.gpa, s.name) for s in graduates)
>>> print(m)
(2.0, 'Geoff')
```

I didn't know max could operate on a tuple. It looks like it's only comparing the first position of the tuple.

Comment: `max` can operate on any iterable (like the generator expression you’re using here), or a sequence of positional arguments.  It uses standard comparators, which for tuples means comparing elements in order (ie first element first, second element to break ties, etc).

Comment: Python compares tuples element-wise, the second position (etc.) only gets considered to break ties.

Comment: Re. "It looks like it's only comparing the first position of the tuple.", what result did you actually expect/want?